# Are generic classes not supported as models in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, entity-framework, orm

I am trying to do something like this :

```
public class TrackerContext : DbContext
{
    public bool TrackNewValues { get; set; }

    public TrackerContext(bool trackNewValues = false)
        : base()
    {
        TrackNewValues = trackNewValues;
    }

    public TrackerContext(string connectinString, bool trackNewValues = false)
        : base(connectinString)
    {
        TrackNewValues = trackNewValues;
    }

    public DbSet<AuditLog<string>> AuditLog { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AuditLogChild> LogChildren { get; set; }
}



public class AuditLog<UserIdOrUserNameColumnType>
{
    public AuditLog()
    {
        Children = new List<AuditLogChild>();
    }

    [Key]
    public Guid AuditLogID { get; set; }

    public UserIdOrUserNameColumnType UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTimeOffset EventDateUTC { get; set; }
}
```

But I guess `DbSet<AuditLog<string>>` is not supported. I get this error:

> Additional information: The type 'TrackerEnabledDbContext.AuditLog`1[System.String]' was  not mapped. 
>       Check that the type has not been explicitly excluded by using the Ignore method or NotMappedAttribute data annotation. 
>       Verify that the type was defined as a class, is not primitive or generic, and does not inherit from EntityObject.

**Is there any ways I can implement `public DbSet<AuditLog<string>> AuditLog { get; set; }` ?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot map the generic type because Entity Framework simply doesn't support generic Entity types. 
When using the EF Code-First approach you need to remember that you should model your [POCO classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd456872%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) within the constraints that allow Entity Framework to create [POCO proxies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd468057%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

This means, shortly speaking that such a class:

- Should not contain any attributes
- Should not be generic
- Should be public
- Must not be sealed
- Must not be abstract
- Must have a public or protected constructor that does not have parameters

Comment: You know your answer is correct. but I am really disappointed. because it is something which can be accomplished but is just not implemented in entity framework.

Comment: @BilalFazlani: when you have accomplished it, then we will know it can be accomplished.

Comment: I think that is perfectly doable too.

Comment: Were You able to achieve that ?

Comment: @BilalFazlani How would you accomplish the mapping of any type of property (from the generic argument) to a relational DB column, when not all data types are mappable (without serializing to XML/JSON or etc.)?

Comment: @DannyVarod, by throwing a mapping exception for unsupported value types (assuming you want to support value types), or by constraining generic type parameters to reference types so those fields map to valid entities. It is doable, just more work than most people put in to ORMs.

Comment: i might be misunderstanding something but most of my POCO classes do contain attributes and there is no issue with that as far as EntityFramework is concerned.

Answer (score 9):

I have been using generic classes with success in Entity Framework.
If you declare your class and DbSet the following way it will work.

```
public class AuditLogString : AuditLog<String>{}

public DbSet<AuditLogString>  AuditLogStrings { get;set;}
```

[Update]
I have not used this method recently and in the light of the comments on this answer I suggest Pawel's answer instead.
However I have not deleted this answer since I was able to use the method.

Comment: This is very limited in what you can actually do. For example this approach won't work for navigation properties in a one to many relationship.

Comment: @kirsteng @kjbartel You can use navigation properties, but it means you need to propagate the generic sub-classes on the other side and in descendants of the relationship as well. IE, if `AuditLogString` contains a FK to another table (which is using TPH) and has multiple derived classes as well, Then you can't map that from the base class - it must be mapped speciically for each child.

Comment: This doesn't work well. It gets complicated fast and I ran into circular dependencies when constraining between navigation properties