# Entity Framework: map multiple similar classes to one table in similar databases

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have model with table in databases of my clients:

```
public class Doctor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Filial { get; set; }
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public int? DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }
}

public class DoctorConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Doctor>
{
    public DoctorConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("DOCTOR");
        Property(d => d.Id).HasColumnName("DCODE").IsRequired();
        Property(d => d.Filial).HasColumnName("FILIAL");
        Property(d => d.ShortName).HasColumnName("DNAME");
        Property(d => d.FullName).HasColumnName("FULLNAME");
        Property(d => d.Phone).HasColumnName("DPHONE");

        Property(d => d.DepartmentId).HasColumnName("DEPNUM");            

        HasKey(d => d.Id);            
        HasOptional(d => d.Department).WithMany(dep => dep.Doctors).HasForeignKey(d => d.DepartmentId);            
    }

}
```

Recently additional clients came. Their databases has mostly the same models, but some fields had changed types from int to long.
The new Doctor model looks like:

```
public class Doctor
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long Filial { get; set; }
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public long? DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }
}
```

How to properly map new Doctor model format to the same table "DOCTOR"?

The application uses Firebird database. Version for "old" clients doesn't support long numbers format.

In case of creating similar Doctor configuration, an error appears:
"The entity types 'DoctorInt' and 'Doctor' cannot share table 'DOCTOR' because they are not in the same type hierarchy or do not have a valid one to one foreign key relationship with matching primary keys between them."

I know about Table-per-Hierarchy (TPH) Inheritance. Looks like it can't help in this situation.

The type Doctor is only the one of the many similar types with this problem. The code in an application is connected with first models format. I wouldn't like to change it all...
I would like to reuse existing functionality.

Comment: Assuming that the id fields are the primary key I don't think you can.

Comment: Just to be sure... you have `int` and `long`, but you only ever expect int compatible values, right? Also, I don't really understand your scenario yet... are both doctor classes supposed to exist within the same application, in the same DbContext, targeting different (but similar) databases or the exact same database instance? ...

Comment: @grek40 I suppose, that in this case, I have to have `int` and `long` compatible values. Old clients have the versions of Firebird databases, where `long` is unsupported. New client have database version with `long`. I can convert int to long in code. Operations in code are going to be in `long`.

Comment: @grek40 "both doctor classes supposed to exist within the same application, in the same DbContext, targeting different (but similar) databases or the exact same database instance?" - yes, you are right. But, I would like to know about other scenarios, if they are possible.

Comment: @Andriy this wasn't really a "yes" or "no" question, instead you should explain in more detail what you want to re-use exactly. For mapping between code classes and database tables, the following Q/A may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14813051/5265292

Answer (score 0):

If I don't misunderstand, you need to support old and new databases with the same code and databases only differs on the size of IDs

An approach is to use generics and conditional compilation

```
public class Doctor<T> {
    public T Id { get; set; }
    public int Filial { get; set; }   //Suposing Filial is not a foreing key
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public T? DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }

}
```

When istantiating:

```
#ifdef USELONG
var d = new Doctor<long>();
#else
var d = new Doctor<int>();
#endif
```

Or with a factory pattern (where CreateDoctor may be a static method of Doctor class):

```
var d = Doctor.CreateDoctor();
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but after implementing this approach, an error rise: "The type 'Schedule.DB.Models.Doctor`1[System.Int32]' was not mapped. Check that the type has not been explicitly excluded by using the Ignore method or NotMappedAttribute data annotation. Verify that the type was defined as a class, is not primitive or generic, and does not inherit from EntityObject."  Looks like generic classes are not supported as models in Entity Framework: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21513534/are-generic-classes-not-supported-as-models-in-entity-framework